# Replacing values in similar jsons

Tags: javascript, json, object

Consider such situation: I have two complex jsons - one has a full list of properties and the other is theoretically the same, but can be missing some values. I need to overwrite the values in the first one using the partial one.

How can I achieve this? I tried something like this:

```
function ObjectValues(data) {
                var isArray = data instanceof Array;
                for (var key in data) {
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        if (typeof (data[key]) == "object") {
                            if (!isArray) {
                                profileData[key] = data[key];
                            }
                            ObjectValues(data[key]);
                        } else if (!isArray) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ObjectValues(data);
```

the idea is to loop through the partial json (data) and overwrite corresponding values in profileData. This function can loop through the structure all right (whenever there's an object within an object it starts itself on this level), but I don't know how to make it overwrite the values on each level, as profileData[key] = data[key] is not sufficient

Edit: 
a simple example would be:

```
Data = { 
    "activity": {
         "online": [1,1,3,4,0,1,0,3,2],
         }
    },
    "location": "Antarctica",
}

profileData = { 
    "activity": {
         "online": [],
         }
    },
    "location": "N/A",
}
```

right now, I'd get

```
    profileData = { 
    "activity": {
         "online": [],
         }
    },
    "online": [1,1,3,4,0,1,0,3,2],
    "location": "Antarctica",
}
```

it works fine on the first level, but then it obviously just appends deeper keys to the root (as you would expect). The problem is retrieving the key path in the subiterations.

Comment: What is the output you get now and what is your expected output?

Comment: Give an example of desired input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use JQuery, then you can just call [extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) instead of trying to write your own method,

`$.extend(true, profileData, data);`

This will overwrite the values in `partialData` with those found in `data`, adding any extra keys from `data` as well.

Comment: This won't work since the values already in the `partialData` will be overwritten with those in the `data`. The values in the partialData should be preserved according to the question. Please use comments to clarify first.

Comment: @CharlieH "The idea is to loop through the partial json (data) and **overwrite** corresponding values in profileData". Also, I do not have enough rep to comment yet.

Comment: Yes. It looks like that by the code he has given. Also it looks that the first parameter shouldn't be `true`.

Comment: He wants sub-objects and arrays to be merged in the same way, "but I don't know how to make it overwrite the values on each level". And the first parameter tells jquery to use a deep copy to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, later he says his method is not enough.I retracted my down vote.